# match inside macro_rules - can not use '_'

Tags: rust

I am trying to define macro for simplification of creation of enum
that is possible convert to/from str:

```
macro_rules! define_enum_with_str_values {
    ($Name:ident { $($Variant:ident => $StrVar:expr),* $(,)* }) => {
        #[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq)]
        pub enum $Name {
            $($Variant),*,
        }
        impl Into<&'static str> for $Name {
            fn into(self) -> &'static str {
                match self {
                    $($Name::$Variant => $StrVar),*
                }
            }
        }
        impl FromStr for $Name {
            type Err = BaseError;
            fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
                let obj = match s {
                    $($StrVar => $Name::$Variant),*
                };
                Ok(obj)
            }
        }
    }
}

define_enum_with_str_values!(Foo { Aa => "a", Bb => "b" });
```

This code doesn't compiled, because of I did not define `'_'` rule,
but if I define `'_'` rule:

```
    impl FromStr for $Name {
        type Err = BaseError;
        fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
            let obj = match s {
                $($StrVar => $Name::$Variant),*
                    _ => {}
            };
            Ok(obj)
        }
    }
```

I got such compile time error:

```
error: expected one of `!`, `,`, `.`, `::`, `?`, `{`, `}`, or an operator, found `_`
  --> foo.rs:74:25
   |
73 |                     $($StrVar => $Name::$Variant),*
   |                                                 - expected one of 8 possible tokens here
74 |                         _ => {}
   |                         ^ unexpected token
...
82 | define_enum_with_str_values!(Foo { Aa => "a", Bb => "b" });
   | ----------------------------------------------------------- in this macro invocation
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider what happens when you *expand* that macro.  The `match` in question will look like:

```
let obj = match s {
    "a" => Foo::Aa , "b" => Foo::Bb
        _ => {}
};
```

Note the lack of a comma between the `"b"` and `_` arms.  The simplest fix is to ensure there's always a comma after each arm:

```
let obj = match s {
    $($StrVar => $Name::$Variant,)*
    _ => return Err(BaseError)
};
```